# Why $C^2\geq n$ for any real $n\geq 0$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, inequality

I am trying to prove the following statement: if $C=⌊n^{1/2}⌋+1$ then $C^2>n$ for any real $n\geq 0$.
It seems very obvious, but I don't understand how to prove it. Hope you can help.

P.S. I believe that next statement will also be correct: $C=⌊n^{1/k}⌋+1$ then $C^k>n$ for any real $n\geq 0$ and k>0. If it so, then it is better to prove the generalized statement.

P.P.S. What happens if k is less than 0?

Comment: any real $n$? no nonnegative constraint?

Comment: Start by showing $[x]\ge x-1$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Siong Thye Goh, Oh, indeed for n>0

Comment: @GerryMyerson A minor point is that, assuming the square brackets refer to the floor function (with using the $\lfloor$ and $\rfloor$ symbols being preferable to help avoid confusion), you can actually show $\lfloor x \rfloor \gt x - 1$ for all real $x$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I agree with this statement

Comment: Yes, I missprint, there must be ⌊ and ⌋ symbols

Comment: Can you check the definition of $C$ and the inequality? is there a typo?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh, now I seem to have fixed everything

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: Let $n=2$, then $C=2$, then we have $C^2=n^2$.

If what we wanted to show is

$$C^k > n$$

Guide:

- Step 1: Show that $\lfloor x \rfloor > x-1$.
- Step 2: Show that $f(x)=x^k$ is an increasing function for nonnegative $x$.

Comment: Ok, I agree with you.

Comment: Sorry, I missprint again, there $C^2>n$

Comment: But can we prove that $C^2>=n^2$?

Comment: no, let $n=3$, then $C=2$, $C^2=4$ but $n^2=9$.